# How to show Java portlets in Sharepoint

Tags: java, sharepoint, web-applications, portlet, wsrp

Does someone know/have experience in showing Java web application generated UI in Sharepoint? We have a Java web application and are evaluating the possibilities to embed Java-generated web UI into Sharepoint. I don't think Sharepoint supports Java portlets, but it might support consuming [WSRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_for_Remote_Portlets)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As previously mentioned, the SharePoint team released the WSRP toolkit a few months back. [More details available here](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2008/12/05/announcing-the-wsrp-toolkit-for-sharepoint.aspx).

If that doesn't work out for you (I've never tried it so have no experience to share) depending on the UI requirements you can always use the simple route of the Page Viewer Web Part.

This essentially creates a mini-browser (I believe it uses an iFrame) within a SharePoint page. If you're portlet is simply a data entry/display method it may work out for you and it's definitely less work.

Comment: WSRP Toolkit allow to produce WSRP. Consume WSRP can be done out of the box.
(BTW WSRP does not use IFrame, SharePoint kind of act as a proxy)

Answer (score 2):

WSRP consumer support is out of the box in SharePoint Enterprise. You can find a WSRP WebPart on your site if you've activated the Enterprise feature.

The WSRP toolkit allow SharePoint to produce WSRP compatible webpart.

Answer (score 0):

SHarepoint does not support WSRP out of the box. However MS released a WSRP Toolkit.
You can find more information [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2008/12/05/announcing-the-wsrp-toolkit-for-sharepoint.aspx)

Comment: To the best of my knowledge it is available as a separate download, could be they included it in the enterprise edition. Anyway the toolkit can be downloaded from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WSRPToolkit

Comment: The toolkit is only to produce WSRP compatible webpart.  
The out of the box WSRP Consumer WebPart can be use the include WSRP Portlet into your portal.

Answer (score 0):

Actual link
http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blog/Pages/BlogPost.aspx?pID=537